# How to create new vertical Document Group by keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

How to create a new vertical document group by keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2022?

More one: Can I open class definition in a new vertical document group by keyboard shortcut?

If I need to view class definition in new document group, I need to press F12 and take the mouse for select appropriate line in menu, but I want to do it by one shortcut.

[window's menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU0re.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two commands do not have a any shortcuts by default, but you can easily add your own by following the below guide:

Open `Tools`->`Options`
Search for the word "Keyboard"

In the option "Show command containing" enter "TabGroup"

Here you'll now see various commands, including the ones you are interested in:
Window.NewHorizontalTabGroup
Window.NewVerticalTabGroup

Simply add your desired shortcuts by putting them into the "Press shortcut keys"